# SQLite3 on freebsd - compilation of first program

Tags: c++, sqlite, unix, gcc, freebsd

I installed sqlite3 **from ports** on FreeBSD and now does not sure how to correctly use it. So, I have some simple sqlite program from official tutorial. When compiling `#include <sqlite3.h>` with such command `gcc test.c`
got the `error: "sqlite.h" No such file`

So, what is the best way to compile and use installed from ports `sqlite` library? Need I to copy sqlite.h to every program directory? Or how to use already installed `.h` on system? Seems need also link library to the program, how to do this? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell gcc where to look for includes, and you need to tell it to link against sqlite's library, which is probably called libsqlite.so

You're looking for something along the lines of `gcc -I /usr/local/include -lsqlite test.c`.